# Dynamically apply custom logic on every item when creating a batch file in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We have a requirement where users pick the columns to be output in a batch file. Some of the columns have logic like for e.g:- If sex is Male use code 1, for Female use 2 etc.,

We would like to give the users the option to define custom logic. The question is what is the best way to apply this logic dynamically when generating the output in Spring Batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [LineAggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/LineAggregator.html) strategy interface allows you to define how to aggregate an item into a line to be written to the output file. You can implement your custom logic in there. Here is a quick example:

```
static class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Gender gender;
    enum Gender {
        M, F;
    }
}

class PersonLineAggregator implements LineAggregator<Person> {
    @Override
    public String aggregate(Person person) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(person.id).append(",");
        stringBuilder.append(person.name).append(",");
        stringBuilder.append(person.gender.equals(Person.Gender.M) ? 1 : 0);
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Once you defined your line aggregator, you can use it in the `FlatFileItemWriter`:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<Person> personFlatFileItemWriter() {
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
            .name("personWriter")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.csv"))
            .lineAggregator(new PersonLineAggregator())
            .headerCallback(writer -> writer.write("id,name,code"))
            .build();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help. The part where it says 'code' person.gender.equals(Person.Gender.M)  ? 1 : 0);'code' I want to try to use some pattern to externalize that logic and apply it here. Do you know how I can do that? I tried to see if I can use any existing patterns but was unsuccessful so far.

Comment: You can create a class that encapsulates the logic you want and then inject it as a collaborator in the `PersonLineAggregator` (with a constructor or setter). The aggregator can then delegate pattern matching to that class (which you would unit test in isolation, use it in another aggregator, etc)

Comment: Thats very helpful, Thank you so much